# Makefile target gets called twice

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile:

```
 VERSION     = 0.1.1
 CC          = g++
 CFLAGS      = -Wall -g -DVERSION=\"$(VERSION)\"
 LDFLAGS     = -lm

 DEPFILE     = .dep
 SOURCES     := ${wildcard *.cpp}
 HEADERS     := ${wildcard *.h}
 OBJECTS     := ${SOURCES:.cpp=.o}
 BINARY      = main.exe


 .PHONY:     all dep clean


 all:        $(BINARY)

 $(BINARY):  $(DEPFILE) $(OBJECTS)
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BINARY) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)

 %.o: %.cpp
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

 dep:        $(DEPFILE)

 $(DEPFILE): $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS)
     $(CC) -MM $(SOURCES) > $(DEPFILE)

 -include $(DEPFILE)

 clean:
     rm -vf $(BINARY) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPFILE)
```

When I run `make dep` I get

```
g++ -MM Monomial.cpp main.cpp Variable.cpp > .dep
make: Nothing to be done for 'dep'.
```

It seems as if `dep` is called twice. Why is that?

I am using GNU Make 4.2.1 under Cygwin.

---

Also it would be great if you could give me some best practises for this Makefile if you spot some bad design patterns (other than the double call of dep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your makefile contains an `include` directive:

```
-include $(DEPFILE)
```

So when Make starts, before it even considers the target(s) you've asked it to build, it tries to rebuild the file that is to be included in the makefile. Once it's done rebuilding `.dep`, it gets to work on the file you asked for... which is `.dep`.

You probably don't have to explicitly `make dep`, ever.

And you can simplify a couple of your rules in light of this fact, and the useful nature of [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
$(BINARY): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

$(DEPFILE): $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) -MM $(SOURCES) > $@
```